# How do you select a variable localy javascript and change it's value?

Tags: javascript, dom

With window['name'] you can select a variable name while globaly. How do you select a variable by name while inside a function? Is there a way at all?

I have a feeling this question has a simple answer, but I have been searching the answer along the wrong path or with the wrong keywords.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: No, there's no way, and even in the global scope it's usually a bad idea. Why do you think you need that ? Maybe you need to use an object as map.

Comment: You can access properties of objects via computed names; that's what's going on in the case of global variables, which are window properties. You cannot access local variables in any way other than directly by name or by using `eval()`. To echo @dystroy, if you could explain what it is you're trying to achieve, you'll get a much more useful answer.

Comment: Good question - oddly enough it seems even from chrome-privileged code you can't see what a private function's objects are. But I guess that's on purpose.

Comment: I got myself into the idea of building a menu button function. The navbar has 3 buttons that each have their own menu tied to it. On click of the button, the name of the button is substracted and a toggle variable with a simular name would be toggled. Based on the state of the togglestate an animation is triggered.